# If I resize a depth map, do I have to worry about scaling the depth values?

Tags: computer-vision

In my head, if I resize because I want to use a smaller image size, I am only changing intrinsics, so extrinsics (i.e. position of the camera) don't change and I shouldn't worry about scaling depth values when I resize. Correct?

Comment: Are you asking about resizing a depth map or an image? Extrinsic a should not change, but be aware of depth mixing along depth discontinuities when resizing.

Comment: OK that's what I thought. I am using ground truth at a different resolution from a public dataset. Thanks

Comment: scipy.misc.imresize   and there you can select 'nearest' neighbor.